# How to move files from local filessytem to cloud filesystem In laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-filesystem

I have files in my local storage `public/images/users` and I want to move these files to cloud storage `AWS S3` using the Laravel filesystem.

```
Route::get('upload-local-files-to-s3', function() {
        $documentFiles = Storage::disk('public')->files('images\\users\\');
        foreach ($documentFiles as $documentFile){
        $filesystem  = new Filesystem();
        $contents = $filesystem->get($documentFile);
        Storage::disk('s3')->put('documents\\'. $documentFile, $contents)
        echo $documentFile . ' Uploaded. '. '<br>';
    }
});
```

This code uploads the files to `S3` but it creates new folders inside the `documents/images/users` while I want to upload files inside the documents folder.
And how can I create File Object from above `$documentFile` variable name?
 Because I want to use these following functions from the file object.

```
getClientOriginalExtension()
getClientMimeType()
getFilename()
getClientOriginalName()
```

Comment: my first issue solved with using of basename($documentFile) function. now file uploaded  directly into the document folder

Comment: Now how can I create File Object because i want to use these functions.